# Null Pointer Exception while trying to Update or Delete any item using openJPA

Tags: entitymanager, openjpa

I am getting below Exception while I try to Update or Delete any item from database using openJPA:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.replaceObjectField(StateManagerImpl.java:2076)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.com$freightliner$viva$dao$VivaSubgroupItems$pcsubclass.pcReplaceField(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.replaceField(StateManagerImpl.java:3041)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.storeObjectField(StateManagerImpl.java:2473)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.storeObject(StateManagerImpl.java:2463)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.StoreCollectionFieldStrategy.load(StoreCollectionFieldStrategy.java:573)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.load(FieldMapping.java:819)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.load(JDBCStoreManager.java:692)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.jdbc.kernel.WsJpaJDBCStoreManager.load(WsJpaJDBCStoreManager.java:125)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.load(DelegatingStoreManager.java:116)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ROPStoreManager.load(ROPStoreManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.loadFields(StateManagerImpl.java:2937)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.loadField(StateManagerImpl.java:3015)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.fetchObjectField(StateManagerImpl.java:2258)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.fetchField(StateManagerImpl.java:778)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.fetch(StateManagerImpl.java:740)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.RedefinitionHelper$1.invoke(RedefinitionHelper.java:230)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.isEmpty(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AttachStrategy.attachField(AttachStrategy.java:213)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.VersionAttachStrategy.attach(VersionAttachStrategy.java:153)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AttachManager.attach(AttachManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AttachManager.attach(AttachManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.attach(BrokerImpl.java:3244)
    ... 6 more

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different enhancement strategy. You must have set openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses=supported which is leading you astray. That feature is buggy at best.

[You will need to either setup build time enhancement, or configured the -javaagent enhancer.](http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html)